# In numpy, why does flatiter access past the end of the ndarray?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, iterator

I would like to use the flatiter.coords property of a numpy.ndarray iterator, but I am encountering strange behavior.  Consider the simple program

```
xflat = np.zeros( (2, 3) ).flat

while True:
    try:
        print( xflat.coords )
        xflat.next()
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

This code produces the following output:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
```

The last coordinates are invalid - there is no (2,0) coordinate.  This means that I cannot use the flatiter.coords property without further checks, since it will throw an invalid index.

Why is this happening?  Is it intended?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's truly intentional, but referenced element and coords just seem to be one off:

```
Help on getset descriptor numpy.flatiter.coords:

coords
An N-dimensional tuple of current coordinates.

Examples
--------
>>> x = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
>>> fl = x.flat
>>> fl.coords
(0, 0)
>>> fl.next()
0
>>> fl.coords
(0, 1)
```

I tend to agree with you, it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

While I have on occasion used `x.flat` to reference the array in a raveled form, I've never used or seen the use of `coords`.

```
In [136]: x=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)    
In [137]: xflat = x.flat
In [138]: for v in xflat:
     ...:     print(v, xflat.index, xflat.coords)
     ...:     
0 1 (0, 1)
1 2 (0, 2)
2 3 (1, 0)
3 4 (1, 1)
4 5 (1, 2)
5 6 (2, 0)
```

It appears that `index` and `coords` reference the next value, not the current one.  For the first line the current index is 0, and coords (0,0).  So the last one is indeed 'off-the-end', and would be the reason why the iteration quits.

```
In [155]: xflat=x.flat
In [156]: xflat.coords, xflat.index
Out[156]: ((0, 0), 0)
```

Here's how I'd use `flat`:

```
In [143]: y=np.zeros((3,2))
In [144]: y.flat[:] = x.flat
In [145]: y
Out[145]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.]])
```

I would not use it for indexed iteration.

This is better:

```
In [147]: for i,v in np.ndenumerate(x):
     ...:     print(i,v)
     ...:     
(0, 0) 0
(0, 1) 1
(0, 2) 2
(1, 0) 3
(1, 1) 4
(1, 2) 5
```

Or for 1d iteration:

```
for i,v in enumerate(x.flat):
    print(i,v)
```